# Flutter - Keyboard Show and Hide Causes Build Calls

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been recently learning Flutter and came across some strange problem, when I click on the TextField the keyboard will be shown and the `build` will be called for the hosted and all ancestor widgets.

I've read that when TextField clicked, the `build` method will be called, then the whole widget will be rebuilt, but the case that I encountered is somehow strange, since the build is not called on the first opened widget.

**Scenario:**

1 - Open app.

2 - First widget loads and printed on screen: *"First build called"*, and when I click on the TextField, the keyboard pops up and nothing printed on console.

3 - Click on "Open Second", the second widget loads and printed on screen: 
*"Second build called"*, and when I click on the TextField, the keyboard pops up and print: *"Second build called"* (in step[1] nothing printed!).

4 - Click on "Open First", the first widget loads again and printed on screen: *"First build called"*, and when I click on the TextField, the keyboard pops up and print: *"Second build called  First build called"* (in step[1]  for the same widget that didn't print anything!).

Code:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: First()));
}

class First extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('First build called');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("HI Ramadan"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()));
          }, child: Text('Open Second'),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Second build called');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First()));
          }, child: Text('Open First')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (3 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • FLA LX1 • 75U7N18410006702 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

**Questions:**

1 - Why this is happening (Called build on every widget that is not the root of the tree)?

2 - Is there a way to force flutter not calling `build` when the keyboard shows or hides? since I have a form, when I click over `TextField` and typing something, then clicking over `DropDown` the `DropDown` will be shown then hide directly (because `build` called) and I need to click on the `DropDown` one more time to select!

Comment: similar issue to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409531/how-to-avoid-full-page-reloading-when-keyboard-pops-up/57410479#57410479 also add 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false' to your Scaffold

Comment: @Mohammad : I am also facing this problem. Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: @Jatin Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`First` is rebuilt because its position in the navigation stack changed.

As for your keyboard issue, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920150/statefulwidget-page-recreate-when-keyboard-is-open/53920194#53920194) tackled it, you just have to make a slight change to your code:

Change this :

```
  RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()));
      },
      child: Text('Open Second'),
  ),

  RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First()));
      },
      child: Text('Open First'),
  ),
```

To:

```
  RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
          final page = Second();
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page ));
      }, 
      child: Text('Open Second'),
  ),

  RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
          final page = First();
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page ));
      }, 
      child: Text('Open First'),
  ),
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem, the keyboard will call build anyway in the ```step3``` and didn't call build in ```step2``` which I didn't understand why!

Comment: Your question was about the rebuilds caused by navigation events, but I also pointed you to the post discussing the same issue caused by keyboard events. Which, according to the post can be solved using a similar technique, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind you should always write your `build` methods as if they're being called 60 times a second.  So they should be (a) fast and (b) idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Mazin Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9374465/mazin-ibrahim) answer, I managed to solve the keyboard build problem:

Define all your navigator widgets as `final` in case using routes.

In case of using routes, I managed to define all my navigation widgets as `final` fields inside the routes class.

That's stops of recreating the same widget more than once, especially that my widgets are all `Stateless`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Scaffold in a Consumer widget or where it need.